# Implementing an Interface Parameter in Abstract Class

Tags: java

I am getting an error in implementing this abstract method. My goal is to be able to make the parameter any of classes that implement the interface `DataOutput`, for example, `DataOutputStream`.

Abstract method in abstract class:

```
public abstract void writeMethods(DataOutput o) throws IOException;
```

Implementing abstract method in extended class:

```
public void writeMethods(DataOutputStream d) throws IOException {}
```

Comment: You need to implement the exact same signature. What's your question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can't.
By signature you have to implement the method with the same class type

if you want a method more specific you can create another method which will accept DataOutputStream and be called by the implementation of the abstract method:

```
public void writeMethods(DataOutputStream d) throws IOException {
   //do something
}

@Override
public void writeMethods(DataOutput d) throws IOException {
     if(d instanceof DataOutputStream)
          writeMethods((DataOutputStream) d)
     else
          ....  // something else

}
```

}

Comment: Simple but brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. If the abstract method has an argument of type `DataOutput`, you cannot override it with a method with an argument of type `DataOutputStream`. Return types can be made more specific, but not arguments.

You could use generics to do something similar.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T extends DataOutput> {
    public abstract void writeMethods(T t);
}

public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<DataOutputStream> {
    @Override
    public void writeMethods(DataOutputStream d) { ... }
}
```

Comment: This would work if multiple classes could be extended. But the whole point of my exercise was to learn about abstract vs interface classes. And your answer helps with that, and also teaches me a bit about Generics. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The method definition

```
public void writeMethods(DataOutputStream d) throws IOException
```

is different than

```
public abstract void writeMethods(DataOutput o) throws IOException
```

as `DataOutputStream` and `DataOutput` are different. In your concrete method the `DataOutput` can be an instance of `DataOutputStream` but you cannot declare it that way in the method signature.